# Ionic modal is over material date picker?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I came across a solution where we have to modify the angular-material.js or the z-index in the angular-material.css file which is also voted positive in stack overflow. My question maybe a little creepy but please do help me, where can I find the angular-material.js and the angular-material.css file in my project

Comment: Have you tried using /deep/.className {
... your code goes here
}?

Comment: i have tried for the overlay in the component css file like you mentioned, but it did not work , like this:  ::ng-deep .cdk-overlay-container mat-datepicker-content{
    z-index:2000;
  }

Comment: instead of using ::ng-deep use /deep/ .mat-datepicker-content{}.

Comment: no it does not work, refer this link , it has a workaround.. but i need to know where to find those files ..... this is the link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36534630/angular-material-md-datepicker-not-working-in-an-ionic-modal/37310348